# How do you display a custom ToolTip at the position of a given cell in a DataGridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, tooltip

I wish to display a ToolTip at the position of a given cell (just like the "ToolTipText" property does) but with my own ToolTip created in the designer.
I have tried using the following method to display it:

```
    ToolTip1.Show("text", DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]);
```

where: `e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex` refer to the cell in the DataGridView I am trying to use as the position of the ToolTip.

Just as you would with a button:

```
    ToolTip1.Show("text", Button1);
```

But the second parameter of ToolTip.Show() needs to be of type

> system.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window

What would I need to use for the second parameter of the ToolTip.Show() to display it at the position of a specific cell within a DataGridView?

Comment: Have you tried `DataGridView1.Rows[...].Cells[...].DataGridView` or `.ToolTipText = "text"`?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 the `DataGridView1.Rows[...].Cells[...].DataGridView.DataGridView` bit worked. Thank you! I was trying to avoid using the `.ToolTipText =` so that i can have control over what the tool tip looks like when it displays.

Comment: wait nevermind, it didnt work. The change cleared the error, but ended up making it so that the tooltip just doesnt appear at all